# How to display product name,product price and product image in a custom template in ODOO?

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-11

I want to build an e-commerce website in odoo and in qweb template ,want  to build some snippets where I want to show products list and corresponding images and prices . How can I do that ?

Comment: Please provide more details.

Comment: I want to build an e-commerce website in odoo and in qweb template ,want  to build some snippets where I want to show products list and corresponding images and prices . How can I do that ?

Comment: Go through this Odoo document, https://www.odoo.com/documentation/11.0/howtos/themes.html#create-snippets